# Selenum2: Getting same window handle on hyper link click

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Following index.jsp has 3 hyper links (gmail, google, Facebook, java tutorial), I am getting same window handle value even after clicking the hyper links (handles count is increased on every click). Can some one help me whats wrong with my code.

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Selenium Tutorial</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>
        <a href="https://mail.google.com" target="_blank">gmail</a>
    </h1>
<h1>
    <a href="https://www.google.co.in" target="_blank">google</a>
</h1>
<h1>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">facebook</a>
</h1>
<h1>
    <a href="http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/"
        target="_blank">Java Tutorial</a>
</h1>
```

**App.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class App {
    public static void waitForNumberOfWindowsToEqual(final WebDriver driver, final int numberOfWindows) {

        while (driver.getWindowHandles().size() != numberOfWindows) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://localhost:8080/application/index.jsp");

        WebElement gmail = driver.findElement(By.linkText("gmail"));
        WebElement javaTutorial = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Tutorial"));

        String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        System.out.println("mainWindow handle " + mainWindow);
        System.out.println("Total handles " + driver.getWindowHandles().size());

        gmail.click();
        waitForNumberOfWindowsToEqual(driver, 2);
        String gmailWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        System.out.println("gmailWindow handle " + gmailWindow);
        System.out.println("Total handles " + driver.getWindowHandles().size());

        javaTutorial.click();
        waitForNumberOfWindowsToEqual(driver, 3);
        String javaTutorialWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        System.out.println("javaTutorialWindow handle " + javaTutorialWindow);
        System.out.println("Total handles " + driver.getWindowHandles().size());

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
mainWindow handle {c0582dd6-8cab-b14c-8820-8d8ef12f8658}
Total handles 1
gmailWindow handle {c0582dd6-8cab-b14c-8820-8d8ef12f8658}
Total handles 2
javaTutorialWindow handle {c0582dd6-8cab-b14c-8820-8d8ef12f8658}
Total handles 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of the window doesn't change if a new window is opened. The same handle is returned by the method `driver.getWindowHandle()` even if a new window is opened. To interact with the newly opened window, you explicitly have to set the context to the targeted window with `driver.switchTo().window(handle);`.

This example sets the context on a new window so the driver can interact with it:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

// open the url
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");

// open a link in a new window with Ctrl + Click
new Actions(driver)
    .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
    .click(driver.findElement(By.id("nav-questions")))
    .perform();

// wait for 2 windows
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));

// set the context on the new window
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
handles.remove(driver.getWindowHandle());
driver.switchTo().window(handles.iterator().next());

// display the title of the new window
System.out.println("Page title: " + driver.getTitle());

// quit
driver.quit();
```

Note that trying to get the last window by **getting the last handle** of the set **is not reliable**:

> The Get Window Handles command returns a list of window handles for every open top-level browsing context. The order in which the window handles are returned is arbitrary.

https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#get-window-handles

Answer (score 1):

`driver.getWindowHandle();` will return the window handle of the currently focused window. To get all the window handles use `driver.getWindowHandles()` in plural

```
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    System.out.println(handle);
}
```

If you want the last opened window you can add the current window to list each time and get it by index

```
List<String> handles = new List<String>();

// open new window

for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    if (!handles.contains(handle)) { // add the newly opened window
        handles.add(handle);
    }
}

// open the next window and repeat the loop (you can make a method)
```

`handles` will have the window handles in the order they where created. And to get the last windoe

```
System.out.println("Last handle " + handles.get(handles.size() - 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. getWindowHandles method returns a Set, Set maintains no order unless it uses LinkedHashSet. When I go through the source code of HtmlUnitDriver.java, it implements getWindowHandles function using HashSet (Not LinkedHashSet). Is there any other generic way to get the last opened window handle?